# Where is the text of Pope Pius IX, "To the Easterners"?

Tags: catholicism, eastern-orthodox, ecumenism, encyclicals

I have seen [Wikipedia discussion of Pope Pius IX's 1848 Epistle to the Easterners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Easterners), and while the discussion mentions a now removed link to catholicencyclicals.net which apparently was a resource on the encyclical but did not include its text, I haven't been able to obtain the Latin wording of the encyclical's title, nor pin down the text.

What is a URL to the full text of the encyclical, preferably on vatican.va?

Thanks,

Comment: [archive-text](https://archive.org/stream/PopeAndPatriarchsLettersOfPopePiusIxAndOrthodoxPatriarchs/PopeAndPatriarchsLettersOfPopePiusIxAndOrthodoxPatriarchs_djvu.txt) or [archive-book](https://archive.org/details/PopeAndPatriarchsLettersOfPopePiusIxAndOrthodoxPatriarchs) .... can't verify

Comment: Thank you... This looks like a near-miss to me. It appears to be on related topic, but the opening words in Latin, from which encyclicals' titles are taken, are "In Suprima Petri Apostoli Sedi," translatable as "In the supreme seat of the Apostle Peter." The document I requested, "To the East/Easterns/Easterners," is titled like one would expect for an English translation of an encyclical's Latin name, but a different Latin name.

Comment: On second thought, I was too hasty to respond. The Orthodox bishops' response, [Encyclical of the Eastern Patriarchs](http://orthodoxinfo.com/ecumenism/encyc_1848.aspx), in English translation refers to it as "To the East," but the first link seems to quote the Orthodox response, which may mean just that I'm missing something about two titles to potentially the same encyclical.

Comment: The Vatican website doesn't list this document with [the others of Pius IX](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-ix/it.index.4.html).

Answer (score 3):

The document that @depperm located at archive.org **IS** the one you're looking for, [pdf here](https://ia800303.us.archive.org/20/items/PopeAndPatriarchsLettersOfPopePiusIxAndOrthodoxPatriarchs/PopeAndPatriarchsLettersOfPopePiusIxAndOrthodoxPatriarchs.pdf).  As Andrew Leach said, the [Vatican website](https://www.vatican.va/content/pius-ix/en.index.4.html) doesn't list this document.

The 44 page PDF document contains:

1. One page of context, from the [***Orthocath***](https://orthocath.wordpress.com/) Nov 3, 2010 blog article [Pope & Patriacts: The 1848 Letters of Pope Pius IX and the Orthodox Patriachs](https://orthocath.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/pope-patriarchs-the-1848-letters-of-pope-pius-ix-and-the-orthodox-patriarchs/) about the origin of the English translation of the Pope's letter (i.e. from the French journal *Irenikon* in 1929).
2. Pope Pius IX letter, dated 6 January 1848 (pages 2-13)
3. Orthodox Bishops's reply, dated May 1848 (pages 14-44)

In the English translation, the title says

> On the Supreme Throne of Peter the Apostle
> *Apostolic Letter of Pope Pius IX, dated 6 January 1848*

But in the French language *Irenikon* version ([pdf here](https://ia800306.us.archive.org/19/items/InSupremaPetriApostoliSede/InSupremaFrancais.pdf)), the title says

> Lettre de N. S. P. le Pape Pie IX aux chrétiens de l'Orient.
> Le Pape Pie IX aux Orientaux

Google translated:

> Letter from N. S. P. Pope Pius IX to the Christians of the East.
> Pope Pius IX to the Orientals

which is close enough to either the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistle_to_the_Easterners) title *Epistle to the Easterners* or the title of the English translation of the reply *A Reply to the Epistle of Pope Pius IX, "to the Easterns"*.

When I compare the French text and the English text using Google translate of the first and last paragraphs, they are the same.